# Change div image on mousedown and revert on mouseup

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, mousedown, mouseup

I am trying to change the image on `mousedown` and revert back to the initial image on `mouseup`.
The image is changing on `mousedown` but it is not reverting to the initial image on `mouseup`.
The alert in the `mouseup` function doesn't appear...  What is going wrong?

```
$(#mydivid).bind('mousedown', function() {
        document.getElementById(mydivid).style.backgroundImage = "url(Images/new.png)";
        alert("mousedown");
    });


    
    $(#mydivid).bind('mouseup', function() {
        document.getElementById(mydivid).style.backgroundImage = "url(Images/initial.png)";
alert("mouseup");
    });
```

I have observed that when I bind more than one event to the same div, the first eventhandler works and the others are ignored... How do I ensure that all events are handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the alerts. That's causing the problem.

Another thing i noticed is that '#mydivid' isn't encapsulated in quotes.

Also, if you're using jquery 1.7+, then it is recommended to use 'on' instead of 'bind'.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

JQuery also has a method to change the CSS properties of an element. Maybe you could consider that too for changing the background.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

---

But, like i said, remove the alerts and it should work just fine. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fS9Ct/1/